# Given two Linux static libraries, how to tell if one depends on the other?

Tags: linux, gcc, static-libraries, ld, nm

I have a bunch of `.a` files whose generation process is not controlled by me, nor are their sources. When I use them for linking, I want to know their dependencies (`libA.a` depends on `libB.a` if there is some symbol undefined in `libA.a` but defined in `libB.a`), so that I can put them in the correct order in the `ld`/`gcc` command line.

I don't want to do over linking (i.e. specify those libraries twice), because I want to persist those dependencies into `BUILD` file of [bazel](http://bazel.io/), so I want to know the precise dependency.

I wonder if there is some command line tool, given `libA.a` and `libB.a`, can tell whether `libA.a` depends on `libB.a`? If there is not such, how do I write such a script?

Note: my definition for *dependency* may not be 100% accurate. Let me know if there are other types of dependency other than defined/undefined symbols.

The simplest way is to process the output of `nm libA.a` and `nm libB.a` and look for `U` symbols, but there are many types of symbols listed in `man nm`, each of them have different semantic, so I am concerned I might miss some if I use such simplified approach.

Comment: static libraries don't depend on any other lib in definitive.

Comment: @IporSircer, they don't have dependency encoded into the file format like `.so` files, but they do have dependencies. If `libA.a` depends on `libB.a`, then in `ld` command line `libA.a` should be placed before `libB.a`, due to the way `ld` works.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the approach beginning with `U` symbols.  In practice, the uppercase *symbol types* are all you need to be concerned with (those are what you link against).  I wrote scripts to print the exported and imported symbols, and for this case, it would be enough to do

```
exports libB.a >libB-exports
externs libA.a >libA-externs
comm libB-exports libA-externs >libA-needs-libB
```

to list symbols where libA would use a symbol from libB (the lists are sorted, so `comm` should "just work").  If those were shared libraries, the scripts would have to be modified (adding a `-D` option to `nm).

Further reading:

- [**`exports`** script to show which symbols are exported from a collection of object files](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:exports)
- [**`externs`** display all external symbols used by a collection of object files](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:externs)
- [download-link](http://invisible-island.net/datafiles/release/buildscripts.tar.gz)